# Как сделать переход из одного контроллера в другой по событию

Tags: objective-c

Коллеги, хэлп!
Подскажите, плз, как сделать переход из одного контроллера в другой по событию. Например: в одном контроллере происходит какое-либо действие (к примеру делается проверка на TRUE-FALSE ) и если TRUE, то переход в другой контоллер.
За ранее спасибо.
Делалл так:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];     
ViewController1 *testViewController = (ViewController1 *)[storyboard
                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
NSLog(@"Контроллер: %@", testViewController);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
```

Лог выводится, но перехода не происходит.

Comment: а где второй контроллер? как я понял self это и есть ViewController1.

Comment: >Получилось сделать без Navigation Controller.

presentViewController и pushViewController это разные методы для разных объектов. Почитайте чем они отличаются.

Answer (score 1):

допустим есть у вас в storyboard два контроллера ViewController1 и ViewController2.

В первом у вас что-то происходит, затем вы нажимаете кнопку (или любое событие) и проверяете что-то.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    if ("условие") //ваше условие
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *testViewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"]; // проверьте ID в storyboard !!!
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController2 animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            //код
        }
}
```

// исправлено

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Наверное я не точно вопрос задал.
Есть два контроллера ViewController1 и ViewController2. 
В ViewController1 делаем какую-ниб проверку и если условие выполняется, то должен загружаться ViewController2 без всяких кнопок. 
Вопрос: какой код должен быть в ViewController1, чтобы загрузился ViewController2?

Comment: ViewController2 testViewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"]; // проверьте ID в storyboard !!!
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController2 animated:YES];

Comment: такой как я написал, только вставьте его в свое событие, в тот момент где вы хотите делать проверку.

Comment: Если написать точно как Вы предлагаете, то пишет ошибку "No known class method for selector instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"

Если добавить строку UIStoryboard storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];  то ничего не происходит, как был 1-й контроллер так и остаётся, 2-й не показывается

Comment: а в storyboard перед ViewController1 есть Navigation Controller?

Comment: Нет. Есть просто ViewController.

Comment: вот вам проектик, пока лежит мой сервер ) http://dropmefiles.com/vIZIm

только условие свое поставьте

Comment: То что надо!!!! Моя благодарность просто не знает границ! Спасибо огромное.
Скажите, а без Navigation Controller это можно сделать? Если можно сделать переход из одного контроллера в другой по IBAction, то по событию тоже наверное как-то можно или я ошибаюсь?

Получилось сделать без Navigation Controller.

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController1 *testViewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; 
    [self presentViewController:testViewController2 animated:YES completion: Nil];

Comment: > а без Navigation Controller это можно сделать? 

тогда нужно будет добавить его в коде.

> Если можно сделать переход из одного контроллера в другой по IBAction, то по событию тоже наверное как-то можно или я ошибаюсь?

в том проекте, что я выложил, не по IBAction. Там просто при загрузке ViewController1 идет проверка на условие, которое сейчас всегда true. И сразу переходит на ViewController2. Просто подставьте код из блока if в свой if.

И обязательно обратите внимание на идентификатор у ViewController2 в сториборде.